# How to filter duplicate sub-arrays of integers and strings from two dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I am receiving a 2-dimensional array of both integers and strings, and I want to remove duplicates from them:

original array = `[["admin", 2, "regular"], ["customer", "regular"], ["regular", "customer"], [1], ,["admin"], [1], ["admin"]`

expected result = `[["admin", 2, "regular"], ["customer", "regular"], [1], ["admin"]]`

Please how can I do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it matter if your array (and it's sub-arrays) gets reordered? If it doesn't, then:

```js
var array = [["admin", 2, "regular"], ["customer", "regular"], ["regular", "customer"], [1],["admin"], [1], ["admin"]];

array = array.map(x => x.sort()).sort();

var uniqueArray = [];
uniqueArray.push(array[0]);

for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
  if (JSON.stringify(array[i]) != JSON.stringify(array[i-1])){
      uniqueArray.push(array[i]);
      }
}

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort a copy from the inner arrays and build a string and check against a hash table while filtering.

```js
var array = [["admin", 2, "regular"], ["customer", "regular"], ["regular", "customer"], [1], ["admin"], [1], , ["admin"]],
    object = Object.create(null),
    unique = array.filter(function (a) {
        var b = a.slice().sort().join('|');
        return !object[b] && (object[b] = true)
    });
    
console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm that might help you. It is NOT javascript written. 
And it does not do the difference between ["customer", "regular"] and ["regular", "customer"], but you have the general idea :

```
var newArray = [];
for(x in originalArray) { //travel in the original array
var flag = 1; //flag indicating if x is already in newArray
   for(y in array) { 
     if(y == x) flag = 0; //if x already belongs to newArray
   }
   if(flag==1) newArray += x; //add if not already in newArray
flag = 1; //reset value of flag
}
```

Basically, you create a new array in which you add only value that do not already belong to it. Good luck :)